# How to open an .exe in the PyQt window itself?

Tags: python, pyqt, subprocess, exe, qprocess

I have a program named RSPEC.EXE, and i want to open it inside a PyQT widget. this code works for me:

```
btnspect = QPushButton("spect", self)    
btnspect.resize(50, 20)    
btnspect.move(300, 10)
btnspect.clicked.connect(lambda:subprocess.Popen([r"C:\Python365\RSPEC.exe"]))
```

this opens the exe file in a different windows, but i want it embedded in the     Qt window itself. (and if possible also interact with the buttons of this exe through the python program (future problem) ) Can somebody tell me how to do this?

Comment: @eyllanesc i read that answer but (couldn't comment there)
this did not work for me; issue: i do not want to run in win32gui rather QtGui ; but anyway, i tried both of them, the program runs but nothing happens; GUI doesn't show up ... not even my original GUI (which had many other things except the exe invoked)